# Pagination with changing content

Tags: php, mysql

This is a known issue for every developer when using pagination. I did not found any simple solutions, except using something complicated like google pagination cursor.

We have the next scenario: Our pagination object has 5 items per page and 10 items in total

1. Page 1 will display: item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
2. We delete item4 and item5
3. Page 2 will display: item8, item9, item10
4. Issue: items6 and item7 disappears because they were moved in page 1

So the perfect scenario will be for Page 2 to display item6, item7, item8, item9 and item10. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ID of the news-item to offset your DB-limit.

`` $offset_id = $_GET['offset'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`>'".$offset_id."' LIMIT 5"; ``

Note: The code above is vulnerable to SQL-injections, using the code above your responsibility, it's just an example.

Comment: yea, but this is not a general rule, because the items can be ordered by something else than the id.